# JQuery trigger element itself in a bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, bind

Can someone explain me why this snippet can't work ?

I can't use specific features like window.location, submit(), (instead of trigger()), because this function is bound to elements that are very differents.

```
$('a, button').bind('click', function(oEvent, oData) {
    var oButton = $(this);
    var bSkip   = (oData && oData.skip);

    if(true === bSkip) {
        return true;
    } else {
        oEvent.preventDefault();
        //oEvent.stopPropagation();

        if(confirm('This is a confirm box')) {
            $(oButton).trigger('click', { skip: true });
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance ! ;)

Comment: It would be great if you can create the fiddle for same.

Comment: Instead of button, give as input[type=button], If you give as "button" it will not work. Check jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/sxwfm/

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam or use ':button' to handle both case

Comment: Even though you trigger the click event, it will not execute all the default actions associated with the event because of browser security constrains like submitting a form or redirecting on an anchor element etc

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes that also will yield the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case even though the click event gets fired the default behavior of the links may not be triggered because of the constraints imposed by the browser

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly(if the action s not confirmed then cancel the default behavior), then you can achieve it by the below... there is no need to fire the event again

```
$('a, button').bind('click', function (oEvent, oData) {
    if (confirm('This is a confirm box')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        oEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rNbmk/)